# Array Assignment with Autograd ( not again :( )

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch, autograd

I have a fairly non trivial function I want to differentiate with `autograd` but I'm not quite enough of a numpy wizard to figure our how to do it without array assingment.

I also apologize that I had to make this example incredibly contrived and meaningless to be able to run standalone. The actual code I'm working with is for non linear finite elements and is trying to compute the jacobian for a complex non linear system.

```py
import autograd.numpy as anp
from autograd import jacobian

def alpha(x):
    return anp.exp(-(x - 10) ** 2) / (x + 1)


def f(x):
    # Matrix getting constructed
    k = anp.zeros((x.shape[0], x.shape[0]))

    # loop over some random 3 dimensional vectors
    for element in anp.random.randint(0, x.shape[0], (x.shape[0], 3)):

        # select 3 values from x
        x_ijk = anp.array([[x[i] for i in element]])

        norm = anp.linalg.norm(
            x_ijk @ anp.vstack((element, element)).transpose()
        )

        # make some matrix from the element
        m = element.reshape(3, 1) @ element.reshape(1, 3)

        # alpha is an arbitrary differentiable function R -> R
        alpha_value = alpha(norm)

        # combine m matricies into k scaling by alpha_value
        n = m.shape[0]
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                k[element[i], element[j]] += m[i, j] * alpha_value

    return k @ x


print(jacobian(f)(anp.random.rand(10)))
# And course we get an error
# k[element[i], element[j]] += m[i, j] * alpha_value
# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I don't really understand this message since no type error is happening. I assume it must be from assignment.

After writting the above I made a trivial switch to `PyTorch` and the code runs just fine. But I would still prefer to use `autograd`

```py
#pytorch version
import torch
from torch.autograd.gradcheck import zero_gradients


def alpha(x):
    return torch.exp(x)


def f(x):
    # Matrix getting constructed
    k = torch.zeros((x.shape[0], x.shape[0]))

    # loop over some random 3 dimensional vectors
    for element in torch.randint(0, x.shape[0], (x.shape[0], 3)):

        # select 3 values from x
        x_ijk = torch.tensor([[1. if n == e else 0 for n in range(len(x))] for e in element]) @ x
        norm = torch.norm(
            x_ijk @ torch.stack((torch.tanh(element.float() + 4), element.float() - 4)).t()
        )

        m = torch.rand(3, 3)

        # alpha is an arbitrary differentiable function R -> R
        alpha_value = alpha(norm)

        n = m.shape[0]
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                k[element[i], element[j]] += m[i, j] * alpha_value

    print(k)
    return k @ x


x = torch.rand(4, requires_grad=True)
print(x, '\n')
y = f(x)
print(y, '\n')
grads = []
for val in y:
    val.backward(retain_graph=True)
    grads.append(x.grad.clone())
    zero_gradients(x)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(torch.stack(grads))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Autograd, and in JAX, you are not allowed to perform array indexing assignments. See the [JAX gotchas](https://github.com/google/jax#current-gotchas) for a partial explanation of this.

PyTorch allows this functionality. If you want to run your code in autograd, you'll have to find a way to remove the offending line `k[element[i], element[j]] += m[i, j] * alpha_value`. If you are okay with running your code in JAX (which has essentially the same syntax as autograd, but more features), then it looks like [jax.ops](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.ops.html) could be helpful for performing this sort of indexing assignment.

Comment: I ended up just computing the jacobian myself and saving the hassle, but I'll look into JAX in the future. Thanks for the help.